# Do synonyms exist?

Tags: c#, keyword

Is there a way to have a variable set to an object and have another variable which is always equals to the former one?

```
var x = new object();
var y = [synonym of x];
x = null; // then y = null as well
```

I don't think this exists.

So I've often used arrays to hold "references".

```
var x = new object[] { new object() };
var y = x;
x[0] = null; // then y[0] = null as well
```

But it feels kinda lame.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You usually have references in C#, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Skurmedel doesn't my example with arrays clear things up?

Comment: When passing a `ref` or `out` parameter to a method you have an alias of the original variable. But you cannot do this within a single method.

Comment: @Serge: No problem, I see what you mean now. You want to modify the reference, not the object you are referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it but the price you have to pay is to use undocumented keywords/features. They're there from long time ago and probably they won't change or disappear but...

It'll make your code more complicated to read (it may be useful if supported by the language itself) but it's bidirectional and you can move around your original object, changes will always be reflected to your "reference" too. It differs from Mehmet Ataş answer because you can **pass the original object to another function** and **changes will propagate** to your synonym too. They have limitations (they can't be used for class fields) but they works for parameters and local variables.

What you need is a `TypedReference`, it holds a **reference** to another variable then if you assign a new value to it you'll change the original variable. This in theory could open the door to synonyms if someday they'll think it's a good feature to include.

Let's see an example:

```
var text = "initial value";
var synonym = __makeref(text);
```

Now `synonym` is a reference to text (please note it's a reference to `text` and not to the value it holds). To get original value from a `TypedReference` you use `__refvalue` like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(__refvalue(synonym, string));
```

They have the same value:

```
Debug.Assert(__refvalue(synonym, string) == text);
```

Now let's change text to a new value:

```
text = "second value";
Debug.Assert(__refvalue(synonym, string) == text);
```

And even opposite is true:

```
__refvalue(synonym, string) = "third value"; // <---
Debug.Assert(__refvalue(synonym, string) == text);
```

Finally let's modify the original variable within another function (unaware of the reference it'll see a **normal** variable):

```
void ChangeIt(ref string value) { value = "another value"; }

ChangeIt(ref text);
Debug.Assert(__refvalue(synonym, string) == text);
```

All of this works will value types as well. Note that this creates a synonym for a variable, not an alias (you can imagine them as a safe pointer - to pointer in case of reference type). Let's try this:

```
void foo1()
{
    string text = "ABC";
    foo2(text);

    // text holds the original value "ABC"
    // not the value modified in foo2
}

void foo2(string value)
{
   value = "123";
   var synonym = __makeref(value);
   __refvalue(value, string) = "456";

   // both value and synonym holds "456";
}
```

Comment: It's not improving readability at all, but it answers the question. I'm glad to learn about those (even if I won't use actually them).

Comment: @Serge yes I wouldn't suggest to use them in any true program (and not only because they're undocumented). I never had the feeling I would need this feature (synonyms) in C# but...this is the first true use I can imagine for that keywords! LOL

Answer (score 5):

If you really really need to this you can do something like below but I think it is still lame (:

```
class RefHolder<T>
{
    public RefHolder(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Usage

```
var o1 = new RefHolder<object>(new object());
var o2 = o1;
o2.Value = null; // now o1.Value is null too
```

Comment: he says to write: o1 = null and o2 becomes null automatically.

Comment: I see, that's why this is still lame.

Comment: @Tigran, I'm glad to have alternatives suggestions though.

Comment: I guess, everything will end with something like this... Good approach.

Comment: @Mehmet, it's way less messy than the array approach. The syntax even look to what you have with nullable primitives.

Comment: -1, no it recalls nullables syntax but you can't use them as parameters of other functions unless you make them aware of RefHolder type (this is especially true for value types).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are basicly describing a C++ reference (or a C pointer).
This can be done in C#, too, but you REALLY do not want to do this unless you absolutely need to.

```
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 5;

        int *b = &a;
        *b = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
```

This will output `0` to the console.

You can read more about unsafe code in [Unsafe Code and Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: In C# you can not have pointer to class, so this approach will only work for some unmanaged types. To see which types may be a pointer type, you can have a look at [Pointer types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. .NET contains both Reference and Value types. Value types are all the basic types, int, bool etc.. plus string. Reference types are everything else, including anything you create for yourself.

So, for example, value types...

```
int a = 3;
int b = a;
b = 5;
// a is still 3
```

While with references

```
class Mine {
  public int A { get; set; }
}
Mine A = new Mine() { A = 3; }
Mine B = A;
B.A = 5;
// A.A is now 5.
```

Comment: My meaning was that no, synonims do not exist per se, but can be achieved by using a referenced variable instead of a value type. Sorry if it didn't come across.

Comment: That's somewhat the same answer which Mehmet gave sooner but with lesser friendly naming.

Comment: Agreed, Mehmets answer is an actual solution/workaround, mine is merely an example.

Answer (score -1):

you can asign like

```
var parentObject={};

parentobject['child1']="test1";
parentobject['child2']="test2";
parentobject['child3']="test3";
```

after

> console.log(parentObject);

you get following output

**object{child1="test1",child2="test2",child2="test2"}**

Comment: Is this a javascript answer?