# C# two objects with the same reference

Tags: c#, dictionary, object, reference

I have base class that save all property value in a Dictionary. but I want to property value and value in Dictionary has save value. if property value change then change dictionary value and if change value in dictionary , change property value. In Constructor I use reflection but after finish constructor I want not used reflection because of performance.

Type of dictionary value is following (in my project its more complex):

```
public class AgentProperty
{
    public object Value;
    public string Name;
    public AgentProperty(string name, object value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The Base Class is following:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private Dictionary<string,AgentProperty> Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, AgentProperty>();
    public AgentProperty this[string key]
    {
        get { return (AgentProperty)Dictionary[key]; }
        set { Dictionary[key] = value; }
    }
    public void Add(AgentProperty ap)
    {
        Dictionary.Add(ap.Name, ap);
    }
    public void SetDict(BaseClass o)
    {
        var objectType = o.GetType();

        foreach (var property in objectType.GetProperties())
        {                
            AgentProperty agentProperty = new AgentProperty(property.Name, property.GetValue(o));                                    
            Add(agentProperty);                
        }
    }
}
```

The sample class that inherited from BaseClass. This class can have any type of property.

```
public class TmpClass : BaseClass
{
    public TmpClass(){
        SetDict(this);
    }
    public string X { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public string Z { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan T { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? I'm not sure what this is attempting to say: _but I want to property value and value in Dictionary has save value. if property value change then change dictionary value and if change value in dictionary , change property value_

Comment: It's really a bad bad bad bad idea to use a mutable property as key in a dictionary. What happens when you change `Name` **field** after it has been added to the dictionary? Not an issue here because it's the name of a property but it smells bad. Anyway, you're creating `AgentProperty` reading the properties of an object, if you want to keep it updated then you have to observe the original object. Check if the object `o` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, that's all.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti where Name is changed??? I can't access the TmpClass only I can change BaseClass. then I can't use INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Chris I want to access a memory of property from two way. from class property and from dictionary

Comment: @sharafi Someone using `BaseClass` has direct access to `AgentProperty.Name`. It can be changed. That said you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the base class but derived classes MUST rise the event. If you can't then you MIGHT use a `WeakReference` but properties have to be reference types. If that's also impossible then `AgentProperty` must not keep a copy of the value but to read the value by itself: `public object Value => _propertyInfo.GetValue(_instance);` (its constructor will then be `new AgentProperty(o, property)`. Note that its properties (`Name` and `Value` are readonly)

Comment: I prefer the last solution even if it has an impact on performance (is it a problem?) if you read the value multiple times. To make it better `AgentProperty` can inspect what the object implements and what the property is and pick the best _monitoring_ method (`INotifyPropertyChanged` if implemented for the object itself or for the property value, `WeakReference` if the property is a reference type, re-reading the value each time if it's a value type or a string).

Comment: MAYBE (I didn't try) you can also have something working with `__makeref` but I'd strongly avoid to use it (because it's not a documented feature).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti how can I use __makeref?

Comment: You can't use it _alone_ (it does not work with properties, see an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365287/1207195) but the point is to do NOT use it. It's an undocumented feature and you can easily obtain the same results using [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223110/c-sharp-two-objects-with-the-same-reference?noredirect=1#comment97182410_55223110).